# mod rewrite Rule for Image + String to Imagefolder Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got some images on my server, which were always generated on the fly and requested right here:
`http://www.mydomain.com/en/images.png?domain=test.com`

They are now cached in
`http://www.mydomain.com/images/test.com.png`

I tried the following rule in my htaccess, but it doesn't work:

`RewriteRule ^(en|de)?/images.png\?domain=(.*) /images/$2.png   [QSA,L]`

Any clue what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just found the solution:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^domain=(.*)$` 
^ this line was missing to catch the Query String
`RewriteRule ^(en|de)?/images.png$ /rating-images/%1.png [QSA]`

Comment: Didn't even think of that. :-) Glad you found it.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, you probably need to escape the question mark that is part of the URL.

```
RewriteRule ^(en|de)?/images.png\?domain=(.*) /images/$2.png [QSA,L]
```

Comment: already tried this, same problem! if i remove the domain=(.*) part the rule works but i unfortunately need the $2 part to get the right filename...

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem? Are you getting a 500? a 404? Something else? If you have access to the .conf file, try adding `RewriteLog /path/to/mydomain-rewrite.log` and `RewriteLogLevel 3` (or `4`) and see what mod_rewrite is doing or complaining about.

Comment: I get a 404 The requested URL /en/images.png was not found on this server.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not necessarily with the rewrite rule, but caused by the server not finding a physical /en/images.png file at some point before the rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

The query string is not part of what you're comparing to implicitly with RewriteRule, you need a RewriteCond to match/capture it to use in your substitution:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString