# Rewrite PHP Query URL to Image with .htaccess Mod Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I rewrite a PHP query url to an actual image?

I'd like *http://localhost/img.php?image=winter.jpg* to be rewritten to *http://localhost/img/winter.jpg* The image name changes dynamically.

I tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+img\.php\?.*?image\=(.+)[$&] ./img/$1 [NC]
```

Thanks.

[Update]

After accessing *http://localhost/img.php?image=winter.jpg* the following text was appended to the log file. The browser shows the message, "Object Not Found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

```
127.0.0.1 - - [<time>] [localhost/sid#975148][rid#4d09cb8/initial] (3) [perdir Z:/xampp/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: Z:/xampp/htdocs/img.php -> img.php
127.0.0.1 - - [<time>] [localhost/sid#975148][rid#4d09cb8/initial] (3) [perdir Z:/xampp/htdocs/] applying pattern '^.+img\.php\?.*?image=(.+)[$&]' to uri 'img.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [<time>] [localhost/sid#975148][rid#4d09cb8/initial] (3) [perdir Z:/xampp/htdocs/] pass through Z:/xampp/htdocs/img.php
```

[Update]

The error logs says,

```
[<time>] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script 'Z:/xampp/htdocs/img.php' not found or unable to stat
```

So I created a dummy file named `img.php` and the error stated not being shown any more. I've assumed that a dummy file was not necessary. Now it only displays the contents of the dummy PHP file when I access *http://localhost/img.php?image=winter.jpg*

I tried `[NC,L]`, `[R,NC]`, `[R,NC,L]` but none of them worked.

Comment: So after doing the rewrite-log, now you need to look into the error log (that is normally already enabled by default). In that error log, the 404 error will be explained, e.g. for which file has been looking for. Also from the rewrite log, it looks like you should mark that rule as `[L]`.

Comment: You want to read this: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/ - the query string part of the URL needs special treatment, you can not regex it in the `RewriteRule`. Bascially the 404 means that you URL is not being rewritten (your regular expression does not match).

Comment: I see. I tried `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^image=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^img\.php$ ./img/%1 [NC,L]` and now the browser rewrites the url to `http://localhost/Z:/xampp/htdocs/img/winter.jpg?image=winter.jpg` It appears the file path and the url are mixed. The page displays the 403 error with a message "Access forbidden!."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. The browser may need to be restarted.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^image=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*img\.php$ ./img/%1 [NC,QSA]
```

Related: [mod rewrite Rule for Image + String to Imagefolder Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730587/mod-rewrite-rule-for-image-string-to-imagefolder-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

You are not redirecting. Add the Redirect flag, try `[R]` at the end:

```
RewriteRule ^.+img\.php\?.*?image\=(.+)[$&] ./img/$1 [R,NC]
                                                      ^
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I access the url, it says "Object Not Found". Sorry I might have misused the word "Redirect". I'd like to just display the image which is located in the img directory with a query url. I'm not sure what would be the correct phrase to describe it for my need.

Comment: Right, that is not a *HTTP Redirect* then, but you are rewriting the URL. Adding the R might help you, because it makes the re-writing visible. Anyway in your case, just enable the rewrite logging and add the relevant part from the log to your question.

Comment: `Adding the R might help you,` - If you mean `[R,NC]`, it doesn't seem to work. `just enable the rewrite logging and add the relevant part from the log to your question` - hmm, I'm not sure what to do. I'll try, thanks.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog - the log logs what happens with the rewrites. this allows you then to see what is going on (and what is going wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the information about logging. I added `RewriteLog "Z:\xampp\htdocs\rewrite.log"` in `httpd.conf` and restarted Apache. It created a file named rewrite.log but despite accessing the query url, nothing gets logged. The file size stays at 0 kb.

Comment: After adding `RewriteLogLevel 9` to `httpd.conf` it has started appending text into the log file. I updated the question.